# Debugging a function in python

Tags: python

I am asked to debug the following function:

```
def buggy_find_max(input):
    max_val = None
    for value in input:
        if max_val is None:
            max_val = value
        if max_val > value:
            max_val = value
    print max_val
```

if the function is called with:`buggy_find_max([1, 5, 3])` it should return 5.
I tried to do it by changing it as follows:

```
def buggy_find_max(input):
    for value in input:
        max_val = value
        if max_val is None:
           print None
        if max_val > max_val+1:
           max_val = max_value+1
           print max_val
```

But shows nothing .How can I debug it.

Comment: Debugging is not just simple trial and error. What's wrong with the original (apart from the indenting)?

Comment: you are overwriting `max_val` all the time

Comment: If you don't mind, use the built-in `max` function instead... `max([1,5,2]) # returns 5`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first version you are supposed to be debugging, ignore the base case (`max_val is None`), because that becomes `False` on the first `value`. Look instead at the second check:

```
if max_val > value:
    max_val = value
```

Imagine your second value, `value == 5`. At this point, the maximum so far `max_val == 3`:

```
if 3 > 5: # False
    max_val = value # doesn't happen
```

Does this seem like the correct behaviour to you?

To comment on your rewritten version (note that, generally, if you are being given a function to debug it *won't* need to be completely re-tooled):

```
def buggy_find_max(input):
    for value in input:
        max_val = value # just sets max_val to each value in turn
        if max_val is None: # this won't be True unless None is in input
            print None
        if max_val > max_val+1: # this can *never* be True
            max_val = max_value+1
            print max_val
```