# Debbugging-For fixing a function

Tags: python

I am debugging the following function:

```
def buggy_dedup_sort_by_len(input):
unique = list(set(input))
return unique.sort(key=len)
```

the list is sorted but the unique.sort(key=len) is returning nothing.
wont the function list.sort return anything.How can I fix it???

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362488/debugging-a-function-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sort`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sort#list.sort) returns `None` because it mutates the list in-place. Try:

```
def buggy_dedup_sort_by_len(input):
    unique = list(set(input))
    unique.sort(key=len)
    return unique
```

Alternatively, use [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted), which *does* return a list.

```
def buggy_dedup_sort_by_len(input):
    unique = list(set(input))
    return sorted(unique, key=len)
```